# Get a numeric variable from database and apply math operations with the input (a number) that user typed on a form

Tags: php, database, forms, operation

I am very new to php and I am not familiar with terms.

I have created a form using RSForms Pro. 
Site user is asked to type a number (integer, demical .. whatever) on a form field. 
The php script will take this number and substract it with a number (float) in a specific table in the database. Something like …

`$Difference = NumberInForm  - NumberInTable`

The problem is that I cannot take the number from the table (SELECT) so that I can complete the math operation!

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this Doc file: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php, especially Example 2. It shows how to access the results from a `mysql_query`. After that, you can `$numberInTable = $row["cellName"];` and do the substraction.

Comment: @coreto98 Updated the answer

Comment: I am one step before getting the value from the table. But it seems that rwo is empty (although I can see the cell in tha table from Cpanel (value=10)

$sql = ("SELECT Points FROM PointTable WHERE Username ='$SenderUsername';") ;
$result = $conn->query($sql); $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)
die($row) ;

Comment: @coreto98 well, try getting rid of `die($row)` at the end. Also, make sure that `Points` and `Username` columns exist in the `PointTable` table. If that doesn't fix the issue, try doing this `$sql = ("Select Points From PointTable Where Username=".$SenderUsername.";");` That would be a better way of concatenating strings.